# Saving an UICollectionView's index path to use in ActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiactionsheet

I'm using an array in my UICollectionView that uses indexPath, and I would like to use the same array with the same indexPath in an ActionSheet. Is it any way to save the indexPath in any way and load it in the actionSheet?

This is the code I am using (I'm of course using more code for the Action sheet, and it workes probably, I just attached the code where the problems are):

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    UIImageView *favoriteImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:750];
  //  UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:500];

    //Sound title
    label.text = [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Single sound image
   // image.image = [UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    // Removes background color in cells
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:190.0/255 green:179.0/255 blue:59.0/255 alpha:0.0];



        if ([FavoriteArray containsObject: [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
        {
            favoriteImage.alpha = 1;
        }




    return cell;
}

- (void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    //Get the name of the current pressed button
    NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if  ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Destructive Button"]) {
        if (self.favoriteAcitve == YES) {


            if ([FavoriteArray containsObject: [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) // YES
            {
                [FavoriteArray removeObject:[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                [FavoriteArray writeToFile:listPath atomically:YES];

            } else {
                [FavoriteArray addObject:[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                [FavoriteArray writeToFile:listPath atomically:YES];
                NSLog(@"Count %i", [FavoriteArray count]);

          //  }}

        NSLog(@"Destructive pressed --> Delete Something");
    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Other Button 1"]) {
        NSLog(@"Other 1 pressed");
    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Other Button 2"]) {
        NSLog(@"Other 2 pressed");
    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Other Button 3"]) {
        NSLog(@"Other 3 pressed");
    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Cancel Button"]) {
        NSLog(@"Cancel pressed --> Cancel ActionSheet");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to remove/modify a selected item(s) in the UICollectionView, using an ActionSheet?  If so, then you can always get the index paths for the selected items using [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

Comment: @MattBecker it doesn't seem to work.. I am using UICollectionView not Collection that is dragged into a normal View Controller ,not a Collection View Controller, if that changes the case.

Comment: It doesn't.  A collection view controller is simply a view controller that contains a UICollectionView and some other stuff.  If it returns nil, then you don't have any cells selected.  Is allowsSelection or allowsMultipleSelection set to YES?  Do you have the delegate set?  If so, you should be able to capture the selections using collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store a variable, try the following:

Use `NSUserDefaults` the code goes something like this:

**Store the indexPath:**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:indexPath.row forKey:@"nameForStoredVariableHere_row"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:indexPath.sectionforKey:@"nameForStoredVariableHere_section"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**Retrieve the stored indexPath:**

```
 NSNumber *storedRow = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"nameForStoredVariableHere_row"];
 NSNumber *storedSection = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"nameForStoredVariableHere_section"];
```

After that you're free to use the indexPath as you please

Comment: I get the following error when using that way to store and retrieve the indexPath, @vborra:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException